# General Problems with ReactNative #1: RCT.RootContentView.h file not found ReactNativeGestureHandler.m

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

This problem arises when there the version of ReactNativeGestureHandler installed during NPM Install isn't compatible with the installed React-Native version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this:

1. Check the version mentioned in the package.json and the actual version installed in the package.json in node_modules.
2. Check the React-Native version mentioned in the package.json and actual version installed in node_modules
3. Check the documentation of ReactNativeGestureHandler for the React-Native version support.
4. Downgrade or Upgrade the version accordingly.
5. ^ in the package.json downloads a higher version, removing ^ and just keeping the version number ensures the same version is installed every time npm install (applicable to yarn as well) is run.

Eg.

My react-native version is 0.58

Intended version downlod of ReactNativeGestureHandler is 1.0.15 (`"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15"`, this installs higher version),

Changed it to `"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.15"`